# Azure batch job task not running on the specified pool?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, python-packaging, azure-batch

I created an azure batch pool with custom image. Now when I create a job from the pool and create a task from the job and run it, the task fails because it does not find the (python) dependency package I preinstalled through the custom image; moreover in the task's overview, under 'Pool' it says 'n/a'. So does that mean the pool that I created from custom image is not being used by the task, and therefore my packages are missing?

By the way, if I log on to a node in the pool, I can see my packages do exist on the nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Using a custom image saves time in preparing your pool's compute nodes
>   to run your Batch workload. While you can use an Azure Marketplace
>   image and install software on each compute node after provisioning,
>   using a custom image might be more efficient.

With the description of the document, the difference between the custom image and Azure Marketplace image is just that you installed the applications indeed in your custom image. So you can run tasks in the pool nodes no matter which image you have used.

For the issues you met, I think it's the user issue which you use to run the tasks. The user permission will limit the use of the application in the nodes. For more details, see [Run tasks under user accounts in Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-user-accounts). I suggest you can try to use an admin user to run your tasks. Hope this will be helpful.